# Issue with retrieving client IP address on a winsock 2 based server program

Tags: sockets, ip, winsock2

Hello I made this program based on the msdn winsock2.h tutorial.I have server program and a client one.Everything works fine, I even made one sided chat from the server to the client, more like broadcast.Now i want to see the client's IP address when he connects.I think i did it right but, on every connect it shows different address in strange form like 12.2.90.0 then, 12.2.46.0.

This is the server code :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{



    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct sockaddr_in client_info;
    char * addr;


    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char buffer[50];
    char typebuffer[50];
    char connected_ip[15]= "\0";
    int port;


    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    } cout<<"Winsock initialized..."<<endl;



    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else cout<<"Listening socket initialized...\nAccepting connections now..."<<endl;

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_info, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else 

      // converting the address in readable form
      addr = inet_ntoa(client_info.sin_addr);
      printf("Client connected, IP address is: %s\n", addr );




    { 
    }




    closesocket(ListenSocket);




  for(;;)
    {

        cin.getline(typebuffer,50);
        strcpy(buffer,"SERVER: ");
        strcat(buffer,typebuffer);


        send( ClientSocket, buffer, 50, 0 );
        *buffer = '\0';



     }

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing a `sockaddr_in` struct to `accept()`, but you are not telling it how large the struct is.  You are not zeroing out the `sockaddr_in`, and `accept()` is not filling it in, so you end up with random results when calling `inet_ntoa()`.  This behavior is documented:

[accept function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526.aspx)

> If `addr` and/or `addrlen` are equal to NULL, then no information about the remote address of the accepted socket is returned.

The `addrlen` parameter cannot be NULL if the `addr` parameter is not NULL:

```
int addrlen = sizeof(client_info); // <-- Add this
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_info, &addrlen);
```